# How do I use data stored in django model in a calculation and then store the result of a calculation in a django model field?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm working on my first Django app, and I need to take the data inputted by a user in my models fields, insert it into a function that makes a calculation using that data, and then returns the value of that calculation to my model where it is then stored.

It is not essential that the result be stored in my database, however I will need to use the resulting figure later on to allow the app to determine which data to present to the user.

I have my model class in models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=gend, default='')
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and my function in a services.py file:

```
def caloriefunction():
    weight = Profile.weight
    height = Profile.height
    age = Profile.age
    isMale = Profile.gender

    if isMale == "Male":
        isMale = True
    elif isMale == "Female":
        isMale = False
    else:
        print("Error")
        quit()

    if isMale:
        bmr = 66.5 + (13.75 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.755 * age)
    else:
        bmr = 655.1 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age)

    bmr = round(bmr)
    return bmr
```

How would I get the resulting value and then store it in my database or keep it to use in another piece of logic?

Would I be better off using the function in the class as a method?

Sorry if the question isn't being asked very well i'm quite a newbie.

Any help if appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add that as a method of Profile.  And/or if you want to keep the result handy you could add another field to the profile model, and override the save method so it is recalculated whenever an instance is saved.  Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.update_bmr()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def update_bmr(self):
    if self.gender == "Male":
        self.bmr = (
            66.5
            + (13.75 * self.weight)
            + (5 * self.height)
            - (6.755 * self.age)
        )
    elif self.gender == "Female":
        self.bmr = (
            655.1
            + (9.6 * self.weight)
            + (1.8 * self.height)
            - (4.7 * self.age)
        )
    else:
        self.bmr = None
```

You may need to guard against missing data.